# how to customize parse push notification to send uri in android application?

Tags: java, android, notifications, push

I want to use parse push notification feature in my android application.
I put my parse push notification code in my first activity (splash activity).

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    // inform the Parse Cloud that it is ready for notifications
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, HomeActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
public void onBackPressed() {

}
}
```

and here is my ParseApplication :

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import android.app.Application;

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, " id", "id");


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

// If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}

 }
```

and here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" ></activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

now I can easily send push notification in application with json like this:

```
   {"title" : "my title",
    "alert" : " my alert text",
    "uri" :"http://Google.com"
    }
```

here I can easily get my title & my alert but the problem is that it doesn't my uri at all when I click on it and it goes to my home activity.
what's my problem? I want to open my uri.

Comment: Who do you want to push notifications to? Just that one user, or all users?

Comment: of course for all the user

Answer (score 11):

You need to add in the URI field the name of an activity.
For example:

.SplashActivity

In my case we have this Manifest:

```
...
<activity
        android:name=".presenter.FooActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_foo"
        android:parentActivityName=".presenter.fooParent">
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="host" android:path="/path" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
```

And the json for the Push using Parse is:

```
{"title" : "my title",
"alert" : " my alert text",
"uri" :"myapp://host/path"
}
```

If you want to open http://www.google.com you may need to have some code receeiving the Intent on your Activity and creating a new one to go to the URL. For that you will need to add a custom attribute for your json to pass the url you need. Something like:

```
{"title" : "my title",
"alert" : " my alert text",
"uri" :"myapp://host/path",
"customurl":"http://www.google.com"
}
```

and the code:

```
Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
if (params!=null)
{
  String param = params.getString("com.parse.Data");
  String url = funcThatGetsUrlFromData(param);
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
  startActivity(i);
 }
```